# swift: flip forward and backward action

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UIPageViewController`. I want to flip my page on button click. I want to flip page forward and backward like `viewControllerAfter` and `viewControllerBefore`. I use this code to flip page but it doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

    pageController.dataSource = self
    pageController.delegate = self

    let firstController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
    let secondController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 1)!
    let contentControllers = [firstController, secondController]

    pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How to fix?

Update

```
extension UIPageViewController {

    func goToNextPage(animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
        guard let nextViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerAfter: currentViewController) else { return }
        setViewControllers([nextViewController], direction: .forward, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }

    func goToPreviousPage(animated: Bool = true) {
        guard let currentViewController = self.viewControllers?.first else { return }
        guard let previousViewController = dataSource?.pageViewController(self, viewControllerBefore: currentViewController) else { return }
        setViewControllers([previousViewController], direction: .reverse, animated: animated, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: can you share a demo of your problem in github ?

Comment: You have implemented UIPageViewController Wrong way see some tutorials to fix it

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya But I haven't error with `UIPageViewController `. And I write this code after watching tutorials. It is code from tutorials. Could you tell me please what is wrong?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I add full code in previous question. For example. I have same code in `createPageViewController()` and if I paste `createPageViewController()` inside my action nothing happens. Could you tell me please now my code is fine? Or I misunderstood you in my previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must have an active pageVC to be able to navigate to a specific VC , also instead of

```
pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You must set only the vc you want to navigate to like

```
pageController.setViewControllers([firstController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and keep track of it's index , so when the user scrolls again the dataSource methods are called to load the correct VC , I have created a demo [Here](https://github.com/ShKhan9/pager) that does the same job

Comment: if I use `[firstController]` I get `The number of provided view controllers (1) doesn't match the number required (2) for the requested spine location (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid)`

Comment: follow the demo i provided

Comment: You not use `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid `. You and I have different code and I not implement your example for my code. Also I tried to solve the problem add new code for question. I have same error and not understanding what I do wrong. please check.